# Can I have multiple Reporting Service Instances?

Tags: scaling

In reference to this document: [Configure a content management (CM) server](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/server-role-configuration-reference/core-roles/content-management/index.html)

Currently we have a 2 server CM setup, and both of them are configured as processing/reporting server roles. This is Sitecore 8.2. I don't know if this is even a supported setup for 8, but it's just to provide background.

We are currently planning out infrastructure for Sitecore 9 and took a look at what this should look like. Scaling out horisontally doesn't seem to be a problem, however at the end of the document it states:

> If you have multiple CM servers, you must set up a dedicated Reporting Service instance.

This sounds, to me, like

- It cannot be on either of the CM servers
- There can be only 1 dedicated Reporting Service instance

Is this correct?   Or will it be possible to assign the Reporting Service instance to one (or both) of the CM instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, my understanding is that you cannot horizontally scale the reporting service. If you plan on running multiple CMs, you need a single dedicated Reporting Service.

There is a sample architecture diagram of the [multiple CM scenario available](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/scaling-guide/scaling-scenarios/scale-horizontally/index.html#multiple-content-management-instances) in the scaling guide. It also shows a single reporting instance.

Additionally, when discussing 'multiple' instances, Reporting is left out of the [scaling guide](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/scaling-guide/scaling-scenarios/scale-horizontally/index.html).

Comment: Cheers :-)   Say we put Reporting on one of the CMs then - would the reports be accessible from the 2nd?   Not directly part of the question, but useful additional information if you happen to know